# node-red ReferenceError: la is not defined (line 1, col 8)

Tags: javascript, node-red

How can i send variables form function to function

[image: First function]

[image: Second function]

Comment: Please post the actual text for code not images, as it makes them impossible to search for. Also when including images it is useful to add a `!` before the first `[` so they get inlined then people don't need to click on them to see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input message to a function node is always called `msg` (no matter what you may have called it in a previous function node).

So in  the example you have given to access the payload of the incoming message in the second function node you would just use `msg.payload`. (so in  this example the  second function node is redundant, but I expect you are actually doing more than is shown)